# Change image height with delay animation

Tags: android, libgdx, tween

I'm using `LibGDX` engine in my game and I started to use `Tween` for animation:

I have in my game a small 'custom' progress bar. One image is an empty progress bar and the second is full one, they booths have the same width and height.What I do is I update it by setting the position of the full as the same as the empty, and when I want to display progress I use:

```
private Image fullProgress;  //its a libGDX image type
//I have already set the process

    float originalHeight  = progressEmpty.getHeight();
    howMuchProgress = originalHeight * process;

    fullProgress.setHeight(howMuchProgress);
```

Any ideas how can I make it change the height with delay animation, so I can see it for a few seconds? better will be to use the `Tween` Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Given your code example, *delay* should already be calculated in the *process*.

If you need to visualize the delay just for the debugging purposes (for example,  for faking the AssetManager's loading progress), I suggest you do something like this:

```
private static final float LOADING_MIN_TIME= 2.0f; // delay amount in seconds
private float loadingTimer;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    // ...

    loadingTimer += delta;
    float loadingTimerScaled = loadingTimer / LOADING_MIN_TIME;
    if (loadingTimerScaled >= 1.0f) {
        loadingTimerScaled = 1.0f;
    }
    process = Math.min(process, loadingTimerScaled); // use the slow(fake) value.
}
```